# Not mirroring layout direction in some of Qt widgets

Tags: qt, layout, qt5

I have an application which  should have a right-to-left layout direction. But there some widgets(e.g. a QComboBox and a QlistWidget) which i don't want to mirror layout-direction (they should have left-to-right layout-direction whatever the layout-direction of app is).
What I'm looking for is something like LayoutMirroring.enabled in qml.
Is there a solution for this?

Edit:

This is a very simplified version of my code:
file widget.h:

```
#include <QWidget>
class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
};
```

file widget.cpp:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent): QWidget(parent){
setMinimumSize(300, 300);
QLabel *label1 = new QLabel("Right to left 1");
QLabel *label2 = new QLabel("Right to left 2");
QLabel *label3 = new QLabel("Right to left 3");
QComboBox *mCombo = new QComboBox();
mCombo->setMinimumWidth(150);
mCombo->addItems(QStringList({"Left to Right 1", "Left to Right 2", "Left to Right 3"}));
mCombo->setStyleSheet("QComboBox{padding: 0 10 0 10;}");
mCombo->setLayoutDirection(Qt::LeftToRight);

QVBoxLayout *mainlayout = new QVBoxLayout();
mainlayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);

mainlayout->addWidget(mCombo);
mainlayout->addWidget(label1);
mainlayout->addWidget(label2);
mainlayout->addWidget(label3);

setLayout(mainlayout);}
```

and this my main.cpp:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);

    Widget w;
    w.show();

    qDebug()<<a.layoutDirection() <<w.layoutDirection();

    return a.exec();
}
```

comment: my project uses a stylesheet file and after playing with different parts of style for QComboBox I realized that the style "QComboBox{padding: 0 10 0 10;}" was causing the problem. So I included that, here. If I remove that line the problem will be solved.

note: I also realized that     `theWidget->setLayoutDirection(Qt::LeftToRight);` will do what I was looking though I don't know it's the proper way or not!

Comment: Are you aware of this doc. [Text Alignment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-righttoleft.html#text-alignment) and [Layout Mirroring](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-righttoleft.html#layout-mirroring)? Seems like that's exactly what you are looking for. (Or did I misunderstand something? I must admit I'm no QML expert.) ;-)

Comment: Yes. I know how to handle layout directions in QML. My problem is with widgets. I have widgets that I want to be left-to-right even if the app's layout direction is right-to-left. for example a QComboBox. I was able to force it be left-to-right by calling setlayoutdirection for that combobox in my cpp file. but still the selected item follows the app's layout!

Comment: How about a [mcve]?

Comment: Added. Thanks to your advice for minimal example I was able to find the source of problem. I also added a workaround that I found.

Comment: If you found a workaround - how about a self-answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, The Problem was with the stylesheet that my app is using. this line of stylesheet "QComboBox{padding: 0 10 0 10;}" was the cause of problem. I removed it and problem solved. Though I don't know the reason.

Also for a specific widget that shouldn't get the app's layout-direction, the layout-direction must be set explicitly. like: `theWidget->setLayoutDirection(Qt::LeftToRight);`

And I realized it from [Qt documentaion](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#layoutDirection-prop)